# Should there be some way to designate answers as deprecated?

Tags: feature-request, obsolete-questions

Most notably for minecraft, but I'm sure this happens with others as well, many questions and answers become irrelevant after a certain amount of time or after a game update.

So should there be some mechanism, like a tag or some kind of flag, to signal to members and googlers that the answers for a certain question might be in fact wrong for the current time period? Or perhaps should mods/members take it upon themselves to edit answers/questions to reflect the time sensitive nature of the information contained therein?

On a side note, this is my first meta question and I was unsure about how to tag it. Retagging as necessary is welcome and appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that this is necessary.

Other SE sites (like SO) have this issue as well. When asking a question, just be descriptive of the version of the game and/or the approximate date. That should be fine, IMHO.